# SolrCore Initialization Failures on JBoss 7

Tags: solr, jboss

I have deployed a stand alone instance of **Solr 5.2.1** on **JBoss 7** using these very simple instructions from the Solr wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall and
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJBoss

I have set my **solr.solr.home** (which points to the folder copied directly from example/example-DIH) this folder has 5 sub folders (db,mail,rss,solr and tika) I have made no modifications to any of them, each has conf and some have lib folders, which I assume is what Solr is looking for....

**solr.data.dir** I have not set in my environment variable as I don't know where it should point to? I had planed to point it to a coreName/data once I have everything running, but that means I can only have 1 core?

Solr does start and I can see the console, however I get the following Initialization Failures:

```
tika: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.DataImportHandler'

db: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.DataImportHandler'

mail: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.DataImportHandler'

rss:
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.DataImportHandler'

solr: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.DataImportHandler'
```

Clearly Solr is looking for these libraries, I just don't know where they are or how to tell Solr to look in the 5 folders described above, I had hoped the war file would have all the necessary libs it needed.

Unfortunately I am not sure what needs to be configured / added next and the wiki seems to lead one to a point and then just stop short of explaining additional configuration steps.

Can somebody point me in the correct direction to go from here?
Also is it possible to secure the admin console (Jboss7 - Solr5.2.1)

Thanks
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Mostly including following in solrconfig.xml should resolve the issue